# Access query if then argument

Tags: ms-access, iif

The argument I'm looking for is, if the Members.Status field is equal to LA and the Member.Isresident field is False then the Members.Locality field will fill "LOST" in that field. I attempted to write it this way and am receiving an error of invalid syntax.

```
Locality: Iif ([Members.status] = "LA" and ([isresident] "False", [members.locality], "LOST")
```

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses in your example are unbalanced.  There are two `(` but only one `)`.

Add an equal sign between `[isresident]` and `"False"`.  And if `isresident` is Yes/No data type, eliminate the quotes around `False`.

Re-using the field name as the alias for an expression can get you into trouble.  You can avoid trouble there with a different alias such as `adjusted_locality` instead of `Locality`.  But if you prefer to keep `Locality` as the alias, bracket it as in the example below.

Since I don't know about the context where you're attempting to use that expression, I'll suggest you try this simple `SELECT` to work out the syntax of the `IIf` expression.

```sql
SELECT
    IIf(m.Status="LA" And m.isresident=False, m.locality, "LOST") AS [Locality]
FROM Members AS m;
```

You can create a new query, switch to SQL View, paste in that `SELECT` statement, and then run it to see whether any errors remain.